# jQuery $.each multiple div names

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello following problem,
i need the id attribute string for each div in a loop how i can make this ?

```
<div id="3r23r32_ProgressBar" class="upload-progress-bar"></div>
<div id="gfdgfdgfd_ProgressBar" class="upload-progress-bar"></div>
```

Here is my sample jquery code which does nothing -.-

```
$.each("div.upload-progress-bar", function (index,value) {

    alert(index);

    $('#' + value + 'ProgressBar').animate({
        'width': 10 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 25 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 65 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 95 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 100 + '%'
    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: `$.each()` isn't used that way... are you sure you didn't mean `$(sel).each()` instead?

Comment: @32bitkid- $.each() *can* be used that way ;).

Comment: why not just call `.animate` on your `$('div.upload-progress-bar')` selector...?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: To iterate the characters in a string? I suppose it may work in some browsers, but it won't do what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

valuetry this

```
$("div.upload-progress-bar").each(function (index,elem) {

    var value = $(elem).attr("id"); // try elem.id, i guess that would work too

    $('#' + value).animate({ // you must remove ProgressBar it is included in the value variable
        'width': 10 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 25 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 65 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 95 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 100 + '%'
    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: jquery objects have no `id` attribute.

Comment: yeah even i have never seen thats why i have written in comment.

Comment: Wow, and I got 3 downvotes for essentially the same answer :).  +1 for answering the OPs actual question.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: If you think this is the same answer, then you don't know the difference between `$(string).each()` and `$.each(string)`.

Comment: As @amnotiam pointed out, I hurried and copied the OP's code over and did not notice that he had a string in place of a selector.  With that minor change, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xcP8e/1/.  The OP was only asking how to get an id of a div, though.  Just sayin'. . .;)

Answer (score 7):

In the callback function, `this` refers to each of the elements you are looping trough, so you don't need the ID at all to animate the element. Just call `$(this).animate(`

But in order to iterate trough the div elements, you have to use `$("div.upload-progress-bar").each(function(`

Comment: I agree that this is great, but the OP asked about how to get an id on each element.  What if he still needs to know that information?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt see the [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. OP makes unnecessary jQuery calls in the loop. Of course, if he really does need the id, he will find in in the other answers ;)

Comment: +1 This is definitely an XY problem. Good job seeing past it.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.id
```

will get you the id attribute's text of the current element.

Example of proper `.each()`...

```
$("div.upload-progress-bar").each(function (index,value) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

See [Darhazer's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792537/555384) for an answer that will probably help your use case.

Comment: i have the divs forgotten please review my question thanks :)

Comment: @SaschaHeim I did, my answer will do what you want.

Comment: SaschaHeim is right -- this will do what you want. @Darhazer's answer is really what you want to do, rather than reconstructing the selector string. In both cases, notice the presence of that keyword `this`. It's a critical concept in JavaScript, regardless of whether you're using a library like jQuery or not.

Answer (score 1):

You want `$(...).each` not `$.each`

It also doesn't look to me like you actually need the `id` at all - use `this`

```
$("div.upload-progress-bar").each(function (index,value) {
    //use `this` and `this.id` if you _really_ need the id
    $(this).animate(
        //...
      )
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$("div.upload-progress-bar").each(function (index,value) {

    alert($(this).attr("id"));

    $('#' + value + 'ProgressBar').animate({
        'width': 10 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 25 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 65 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 95 + '%'
    }, 250).animate({
        'width': 100 + '%'
    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: completely unnecessary use of jQuery here... `this.id` is completely adequate for the job.

Comment: yep, this is what happens when your introduction to JS is actually through jQuery. Not a bad thing -- it's how I learned. But at a certain point you need to start learning pure JS.

Comment: -1 You're making the same mistake OP is. Doing `$.each("div.upload-progress-bar",` iterates the characters in the string (in browsers that will allow it). It doesn't do DOM selection.

Comment: @jondavidjohn- Wrong.  $(this) constructs a jQuery object so that he can call jQuery methods against it whereas "this" points to a DOM object.  "this" would be bad practice when using jQuery.

Comment: @amnotiam- First, the question was not about arguing the semantics of .each() use, it was about how to get the id of an element.  Second, $.each("div.upload-progress-bar") *can* iterate characters in a string, but doesn't always (where did you get that idea?).  They I implemented .each() simply converts the element to an object implicitly rather than explicitly which is the case with the other way of doing it (selector first).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: In your code, each item in the iteration will be the next character in the string. So `this` will be `"d"`, then `"i"`, then `"v"`, and so on... And it doesn't always work because some versions of IE do not allow access to characters in a string using indices.

Comment: If you just do a simple test, you'll see. http://jsfiddle.net/xcP8e/ `$.each` **never** does DOM selection.

Comment: @amnotiam-Oh jeez--I see what you are saying now.  I just copied the OP's code over.  Yes, you are right, that is a string and not a selector.  My bad--I was more focused on the id part.

Comment: Update your answer and I'll remove the downvote. But I'd also suggest heeding the first comment by doing `this.id`. Not only is it not "bad practice", it is a much better approach.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: Hmmm... you posted the same fiddle as I did. Perhaps you forgot to click the "Update" button.

Comment: Yes, that is valid. Since a jQuery object is able to be iterated using a generic iterator/enumerator like `$.each`, you can pass the jQuery object as the first argument, and it will iterate it like an Array. Typically you'd just use `.each()` in the manner you did in your update though.